# Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren

Tags: javascript, jslint

jslint is telling me to do this:

> Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren.

**To this line:**
`"wrapper": (index < allWrappers.length) ? allWrappers[index] : allWrappers[allWrappers.length - 1]`

Inside here:

```
  function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": (index < allWrappers.length) ? allWrappers[index] : allWrappers[allWrappers.length - 1]
      });
    });
  }
```

What would that line get changed to?

Comment: Did you try doing what it suggests? What exactly is unclear about *Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren*?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Parens are parentheses. `(` `)`

Comment: I don't know how to do the other parts. I don't know what jslint wants me to change that line to.

Comment: Note that JSLint is _very_ opinionated (a bit like its author some might say), and might not always align with how you develop code in 2022. You might consider switching to a more modern linter like ESLint.

Comment: I just want to know how to remove the jslint error message.

Comment: Wrap your conditional expression in parentheses, as it says. That's literally all you have to do.

Comment: I'm lost, I don't know what that means to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It wants you to do this:

```
"wrapper": (
  (index < allWrappers.length) ? allWrappers[index] : allWrappers[allWrappers.length - 1]
)
```